# we are unable to access the CGI perl application after Linux OS upgrade from RHEL6 to RHEL7

Tags: perl

we are unable to access the CGI perl application after Linux OS upgrade from RHEL6 to RHEL7.

```
Can't locate Carp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /local/silas/lib2 /local/silas/lib/site_perl /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/share/perl5/CGI.pm line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/CGI.pm line 3.
Compilation failed in require at /ford/eccws6/apache/htdocs/index.cgi line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /ford/eccws6/apache/htdocs/index.cgi line 9.
```

Please tell me what is exactly caused for this issue and do need to make any changes in setup?

Comment: Redhat splits off the standard perl library from the perl interpreter so you have to install a bunch of extra packages to get the whole thing. Very annoying, and likely what you're running into here.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Shawn said in a comment, RedHat splits off core Perl modules into separate packages that don't get installed when you install `perl` or `perl-core`.

I believe you need the `perl-Carp` package:

```
yum install perl-Carp
```